# How to access contact groups in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am building an Excel add-in that sends the active workbook as an attachment in an Outlook email template to a specific Contact Group.

I've gotten the first two parts to work with the code below, but I am not sure how to set the `.TO` field to a contact group.

```
Public Sub Mail_Reports()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object 

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    On Error Resume Next

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Set this line to the path and file name of your template
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\moses\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\test.oft")
    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        '.TO field should be set to the contact group
        .BCC = ""
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, strOldPeriod, strNewPeriod)
        .Subject = Replace(OutMail.Subject, strOldPeriod, strNewPeriod)
        'To display the email leave as is;  to send the Email, change to .Send
        .Display    'or Send
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the name of the contact group (formerly called "distribution lists").  I just tried it, as suggested on [Ron de Bruin's](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/tips.htm) site, and it works.

Comment: Disregard that, it does work. My confusion was that even though it populated the field as a plaintext value, Outlook is smart enough to recognize it as a contact group. I had the answer all along but didn't know it XD.

Comment: I also noticed that it doesn't appear to resolve and should have mentioned it in my answer.  If you hit Check Name it does, and as we discovered, even if you don't it sends fine.

Comment: Hey, old I know, but that link is broken - could you put a relevant snippet of Ron's answer here - assuming you still have it?

Comment: @Huw, Here's a link that has an example part-way down the page. It really does look to be as simple as entering the name of the group instead of the email address. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah that was interesting, but was curious about this guy Ron's solution. Always nice to have stuff to compare. I ended up finding a backup of the site on why-back-when from April 15th (a few days after your post). Not sure if it's worth an edit incase way-back-when loses that in future? Hopefully of use to future stack-overflow users! https://web.archive.org/web/20120415041820/http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/tips2.htm

Comment: Woops, I said "here's a link," but didn't actually include it. It seems to be the same content as what you found in the wayback machine: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/tips.htm. I'll update my answer as well. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the accepted answer to simply use the name, ensure that the Contact Group name is not ambiguous.

For example, if I have two groups called "My List" and "My List 2". When I try to manually send an email and only type "My List" in the 'To' box, Outlook shows a pop-up asking which list to resolve. This works kind of like and autofill suggestion in Excel. If instead I typed "My List 2", Outlook will know exactly which list I want.

Similarly, Outlook gets confused when trying the same things via VBA, and the error message is not very clear: "Outlook does not recognize one or more names".

The simplest workaround I'm aware of is simple to change the name of "My List" to "My List 1" or anything else completely unique, where no other list shares that exact base name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the recipient's email addresses or names resolved (so they don't display just plain text), you can do the following.

```
With OutMail
    '.TO field should be set to the contact group
    .BCC = ""
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, strOldPeriod, strNewPeriod)
    .Subject = Replace(OutMail.Subject, strOldPeriod, strNewPeriod)
    'To display the email leave as is;  to send the Email, change to .Send
    .Display    'or Send
    If Not .Recipients.ResolveAll Then
        For Each Recipient In .Recipients
            If Not Recipient.Resolved Then
                MsgBox Recipient.Name & " could not be resolved"
            End If
        Next 
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way:

[image]

```
  Sub runcode()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Call distList
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub distList()
    
        
    Dim app As Outlook.Application
    Set app = New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Set objNamespace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim re As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim dl As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    
    ' Clear existing data in columns B, C, and D
    Range("B2:E" & Rows.Count).Clear

    ' Loop through columns B and D
    Dim e As Variant
    For Each e In Array(2, 4)
        Set re = objNamespace.CreateRecipient(Cells(1, e))
        If re.Resolve() Then
            Set dl = re.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
            If Not dl Is Nothing Then
                For i = 1 To dl.Members.Count
                    ' Put the member's name in columns B and D
                    Cells(i + 1, e) = dl.Members(i).Name
                Next i
                
                ' Call a generic function to split names based on the current column
                SplitNames e
            End If
        End If
    Next e
    

End Sub

Sub SplitNames(ByVal colIndex As Variant)
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Find the last row in the specified column
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in the specified column
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Get the full name from the specified column
        Dim fullName As String
        fullName = Cells(i, colIndex).Value
        
        ' Split the full name into first name and last name
        Dim nameParts() As String
        nameParts = Split(fullName, " ")
        
        ' Check if there are at least two parts (first name and last name)
        If UBound(nameParts) >= 1 Then
            ' Get the first initial, period, space, and last name
            Dim resultName As String
            resultName = Left(nameParts(0), 1) & ". " & nameParts(UBound(nameParts))
            
            ' Put the result in the next column (e.g., if colIndex is 2, put in column C)
            Cells(i, colIndex + 1).Value = resultName
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```