# Sending email to distribution list using Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I currently have code that works perfectly  that  sends the active workbook I have open to whoever I specify.

However, I would like to send the workbook to a distribution list in my outlook contacts called "Daily Matrix" and want to BCC them. I am not sure how to do that and help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub Mail_Workbook_1()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Daily Matrix"
    .Body = "PLEASE DO NOT DISTRIBUTE-FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the mail.
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the name of the distribution list in the `.BCC` line, but I haven't tested this.

```
.BCC = "Daily Matrix"
```

For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049419/how-to-access-contact-groups-in-excel-vba) and [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/tips.htm).

Comment: Very odd but when I type in the name of the distribution list I get: "Outlook does not recognize one or more names"