# How to send an email to names of people in column A by getting their email address from outlook contact list?

Tags: excel, email, outlook, vba

I am trying to send an email to the names listed in column A but I don't have their email addresses. the email addresses are in outlook contacts. I can get it to display their emails in column B but I don't want to do that. I want to look up the email address and append it to the "To" field in the email. How it looks now is that, it only appends the email address for the last person in column A to all the emails for the other people in Column A. as seen in the pic. all the people in the A column are getting the same email address for the last person in their To field.
[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetAddressesAndSendEmail()
Sheet10.Select
Dim o, AddressList, AddressEntry
Dim ToField As String
Dim c As range, r As range, AddressName As String
Set o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set AddressList = o.Session.AddressLists("Contacts")

Set r = Sheet10.range("A1", range("A1").End(xlDown))
For Each c In r
    AddressName = c.Value
    For Each AddressEntry In AddressList.AddressEntries
        If AddressEntry.Name = AddressName Then
            'c.Offset(0, 1).Value = AddressEntry.Address
            ToField = AddressEntry.Address
            'MsgBox ToField
            Exit For
        End If
    Next AddressEntry
Next c




Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)


    If LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) <> "" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = ToField
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"

            .Attachments.Add ("C:\" & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & ".txt")
            '.Send

            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out On Error GoTo cleanup. Edit your question with the results.

Comment: I did that and nothing happened. The same issue occurs.

Comment: Check out this link regarding your issue     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049419/how-to-access-contact-groups-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1):

Never ever loop through all items in an address book container. If the name can be resolved to a contact, all you need to do is set the `MailItem.To` property - when the message is sent, Outlook will resolve the name to an address. If you want to do that before sending the message, or if you really want the email address, call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` - it will return an instance of the Recipient object. Call `Recipient.Resolve` and read `Recipient.Address` property. If the name cannot be resolved (if it is not found or the name is ambiguous), `Recipient.Resolve` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create each mail before you overwrite ToField.

```
For Each AddressEntry In AddressList.AddressEntries
    If AddressEntry.Name = AddressName Then
        'c.Offset(0, 1).Value = AddressEntry.Address
        ToField = AddressEntry.Address
        'MsgBox ToField

        Set OutMail = o.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
          .To = ToField
          .Subject = "Reminder"
          .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
              & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                "your account up to date"

          .Attachments.Add ("C:\" & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & ".txt")
          '.Send

          .Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing            

        Exit For
    End If
Next AddressEntry
```

Comment: I dropped On Error Resume Next . ..the most commonly used and misused form. It instructs to VBA to essentially ignore the error and resume execution on the next line of code. It is very important to remember that On Error Resume Next does not in any way "fix" the error." http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing it this way.

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm